# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: movie_id

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following tables.

```
    final String SQL_CREATE_MOVIE__SETTING_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + 
    MovieContract.MovieSettings.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            MovieContract.MovieSettings.COL_MOVIE_SETTING + " TEXT 
    UNIQUE NOT NULL " +
            " );";

    final String SQL_CREATE_MOVIE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_BACKDROP_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_ORIGINAL_LANGUAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_ORIGINAL_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_OVERVIEW + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_VOTE_AVERAGE + " REAL NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_VOTE_COUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_POSTER_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "  +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +

            // Set up the location column as a foreign key to location table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + ") REFERENCES " +
            MovieContract.MovieSettings.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MovieContract.MovieSettings._ID + "), " +

            // To assure the application have just one weather entry per day
            // per location, it's created a UNIQUE constraint with REPLACE strategy
            " UNIQUE (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_DATE + ", " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    final String SQL_CREATE_TRAILER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_ISO_369_1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_KEY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SITE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SIZE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +


            // Set up the movie_id column as a foreign key to movie table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ") " +

            " UNIQUE (" + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + ", " +
            MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";
```

And I inner join them as

```
        //This is an inner join which looks like
        //movies INNER JOIN settings ON movies.setting_id = 
        settings._id
        sMovieBySettingQueryBuilder.setTables(
                MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN "+
                MovieContract.MovieSettings.TABLE_NAME + " ON " +
                MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME  + "." + 
                MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_KEY + " = " +
                MovieContract.MovieSettings.TABLE_NAME + "." + 
                MovieContract.MovieSettings._ID);


        sTrailerByMovieIdQueryBuilder.setTables(
                MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                        MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                        " ON " + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                        "." + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID +
                        " = " + MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                        "." + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID
        );
```

I store all json data I get from the movie db api without any problems. I can also display in a gridview the image of each movie. Next I click on an movie and want to display in a listview all trailers (and later on the reviews). However, when I click in a movie from the gridview I get this error.

```
  Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous 
  column name: movie_id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT 
  trailers._id, movie_id, id, iso_639_1, key, name, site, size, type 
  FROM trailers INNER JOIN movies ON trailers.movie_id = 
  movies.movie_id WHERE (trailers.movie_id = ? )
```

All my inner joins are correct. So I don't know why I get this error. I have uploaded my project on [github](https://github.com/theo82/PopularMoviesPart2) so you can have a look.

This is the projection I am using for the trailers.

```
public static final String[] MOVIE_TRAILER_COLUMNS = {
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry._ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_ISO_369_1,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_KEY,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_NAME,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SITE,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SIZE,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TYPE
};

public static final int COL_MOVIE_PK_ID = 0;
public static final int COL_MOVIE_TR_ID = 1;
public static final int COL_TRAILER_ID = 2;
public static final int COL_ISO_369_1 = 3;
public static final int COL_KEY = 4;
public static final int COL_NAME = 5;
public static final int COL_SITE = 6;
public static final int COL_SIZE = 7;
public static final int COL_TYPE = 8;
```

Comment: `trailers.movie_id.movie_id`? What do you want to do with this?

Comment: if you look at your ON clause you will see this `ON trailers.movie_id.movie_id` also you should name set each column to where it belong in the select clause for example (movies.key)

Comment: @m0skit0 I am trying to do this 'trailer INNER JOIN movie ON trailer.movie_id = movie.movie_id'

Comment: @m0skit0 Please see my updated join for the trailers and movies tables. I still get the same error.

Comment: You still have the `trailers.movie_id.movie_id` error.

Comment: @ CL. I updated my inner join but still getting the same error.

Comment: @ CL. Please see my updated error.

Comment: You need to specify table name for `movie_id` column since it exists on 2 tables. Also it is not a good idea to name a column `key` because it is an SQL reserved word.

Comment: @ m0skit0. But I specify the name for movie_id for each table. MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID + " = " +
                    MovieContract.MovieEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + MovieContract.MovieEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have :-
`SELECT trailers._id, movie_id, id, iso_639_1, key, name, site, size, type 
  FROM trailers INNER JOIN movies ON trailers.movie_id = 
  movies.movie_id WHERE (trailers.movie_id = ? )`

The ambiguity is with the first occurrence of **`movie_id`** (i.e. `trailers._id,`**`movie_id`**) which one is it? 
Is it **trailers.movie_id** or is it  **movies.movie_id** ?

So you need to use either `trailers.movie_id` or `movies.movie_id` or both if you want both in the resultant cursor(*1)

It would appear that you may also have the same issue with the **`id`** column i.e. which id column.

***1** If you use both `trailers.movie_id` and `movies.movie_id` the names of the columns in the resultant cursor will both be `movie_id`. You would then have to use the column offset unless you renamed a column(s) using **`AS`**.

You could perhaps use :-

`SELECT trailers._id, trailers.movie_id, trailers.id, movies.movie_id AS movies_movie_id, movies._id AS movies_id, iso_639_1, key, name, site, size, type 
  FROM trailers INNER JOIN movies ON trailers.movie_id = 
  movies.movie_id WHERE (trailers.movie_id = ? )`

#### Addition after comment

> But how to make that change to the columns ie trailers.movie_id and
>   trailers.id. I use the projections shown in my updated question.

```
public static final String[] MOVIE_TRAILER_COLUMNS = {
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry._ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_ISO_369_1,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_KEY,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_NAME,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SITE,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SIZE,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TYPE
};
```

could be (assuming no other ramifications):-

```
public static final String[] MOVIE_TRAILER_COLUMNS = {
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry._ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_MOVIE_ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TRAILER_ID,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_ISO_369_1,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_KEY,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_NAME,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SITE,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_SIZE,
        MovieContract.TrailerEntry.COL_TYPE
};
```

which should give you :-

```
SELECT trailers._id, trailers.movie_id, trailers.id, iso_639_1, key, name, site, size, type FROM trailers INNER JOIN movies ON trailers.movie_id = movies.movie_id WHERE (trailers.movie_id = ? )
```

Comment: Oh I see. Your explanation is very clear. But how to make that change to the columns ie  trailers.movie_id and trailers.id. I use the projections shown in my updated question.